# Notice: Array to String conversion - But it's a string in an array

Tags: php

I know this question has been asked many times, but all of them seemed to have simply put an array instead of a string somewhere.
I'm getting the error in a line that says `getimagesize($page[0]['img_path'])`
Yes, $page and even $page[0] are arrays, but $page[0]['img_path'] has a string in it, and when I vardump it, it also says it is a string.
I'm not sure what to do, I know there's ways to simply ignore notices, but do I want that... it seems unprofessional.

If I do `var_dump($page[0])` I get

```
array(7) { 
    ["page_id"]=> string(2) "78" 
    ["comic_id_fk"]=> string(2) "23" 
    ["alt_text"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["pageorder"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["timestamp"]=> string(10) "2016-03-18" 
    ["text"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["img_path"]=> string(29) "komix\16_03_18_10_25_56-2.jpg" 
}
```

If I do `var_dump($page[0]['img_path'])` I get

```
string(29) "komix\16_03_18_10_25_56-2.jpg"
```

The line that gets the notice is

```
echo "<div class='pageimg' style='height:'" . getimagesize($page[0]['img_path']) . ";'> 
        <div class='pageinline'></div> <img src='" . $page[0]['img_path'] . "' 
        alt='" . $page[0]['alt_text'] . "' style='max-width:100%'/> </div>";
```

the `getimagesize($page[0]['img_path'])` to be exact.

The whole notice says

> "Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\komix_lit\pages.php on line 29"

Comment: If you ignore this notice your code doesn't work. When an array is used instead of a string, PHP converts the array to the string `'Array'` which is not what you want. Post the content of `$page`.

Comment: could you please *show* the `var_dump($page[0])` so we actually have the *possibility* to look at your data? and also show your code so we can *look at your code*? - to cite the site rules: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.`

Comment: Also, the full error message please.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Of course! Sorry I didn't before. I edited and added everything you asked for

Comment: just a note - why you using img path for height value?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs ah, I misunderstood the usage of getsizeimage(), I wanted to get the height of the image for the height value, I will be editing that.

Comment: instead of `getimagesize($page[0]['img_path'])` do `getimagesize(str_replace('\\', '/', $page[0]['img_path']))`; and check

Comment: `getimagesize` returns an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found my Error. I didn't realize getimagesize() gave me an array, which I tried to use in a string. I fixed it now.